# Delphi XE7 Bitmap size to big message on Android

Tags: android, image, delphi, bitmap, delphi-xe7

When I take a picture on my Android phone my XE7 app crashes and it says Bitmap size to big. But I use code i've used before and it worked fine. It's from the example of embarcadero about taking pictures on android/iOS.

My code below:

```
procedure TForm1.TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(
  Image: TBitmap);
var
  saveParams:TBitmapCodecSaveParams;
  directory,name:String;
begin
  image1.Bitmap.Assign(Image);
  saveParams.Quality := 100;
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
  directory := TPath.GetPicturesPath;
  name := '/RoomId:'+ fRoomId.ToString()+' '+DateTimeToStr(Now)+'.png';
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF IOS}
  directory := TPath.GetDocumentsPath;
  name := '/RoomId:'+ fRoomId.ToString()+' '+DateTimeToStr(Now)+'.png';
  {$ENDIF}
  Image.SaveToFile(directory+name,@saveParams);
end;
```

**Anyone know why it doesn't work?**

**UPDATE:**
I know for sure that the code is correct. I've tested it in a different app. Also tried to debug the action and during debug It kept on repeating TTakePhotoFromCameraAction.CustomTextChanged. Also during debug it did save the picture but it couldn't close the action correctly for some reason. Strange thing is that the code also works for a samsung tablet but not for a sony phone.

Comment: Which statement is causing the crash? `image1.Bitmap.Assign(Image);` ? Remove all other code to find out.

Comment: None, it crashes on the action itself. I tried to debug but it gave the message before it ran any code in the method.

Comment: Maybe some initializer should be run on saveparams to initialize the other fields?

Comment: If your app crashes on -which?- the action itself then why do you post that code?

Comment: @greenapps because the action is a standerd action of the TActionList and can't show any code of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a ScaleBy property for the form and this was the problem. After renaming the property I didn't have the issue anymore.